# Getting null safety errors when tried to get autocomplete location of places in Flutter and display details on tapped place

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

I tried to migrate the no null safety code to null safety and I ended up with errors. I want to get autocomplete location of places in Flutter and display details on the tapped place.

Screenshots of errors:

[image]

[image]

The code:

`main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_places_flutter/address_search.dart';
import 'package:google_places_flutter/place_service.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Google Places Demo',

      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Places Autocomplete Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String? title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  String? _streetNumber = '';
  String? _street = '';
  String? _city = '';
  String? _zipCode = '';

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title!),
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              readOnly: true,
              onTap: () async {
                // generate a new token here
                final sessionToken = Uuid().v4();
                final Suggestion? result = await showSearch(
                  context: context,
                  delegate:AddressSearch(sessionToken),
                );
                // This will change the text displayed in the TextField
                if (result != null) {
                  final placeDetails = await PlaceApiProvider(sessionToken)
                      .getPlaceDetailFromId(result.placeId);
                  setState(() {
                    _controller.text = result.description!;
                    _streetNumber = placeDetails.streetNumber;
                    _street = placeDetails.street;
                    _city = placeDetails.city;
                    _zipCode = placeDetails.zipCode;
                  });
                }
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                icon: Container(
                  width: 10,
                  height: 10,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.home,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                hintText: "Enter address",
                border: InputBorder.none,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, top: 16.0),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Text('Street Number: $_streetNumber'),
            Text('Street: $_street'),
            Text('City: $_city'),
            Text('ZIP Code: $_zipCode'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`address_search.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_places_flutter/place_service.dart';

class AddressSearch extends SearchDelegate<Suggestion?> {
  AddressSearch(this.sessionToken) {
    apiClient = PlaceApiProvider(sessionToken);
  }

  final sessionToken;
  late PlaceApiProvider apiClient;

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        tooltip: 'Clear',
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = '';
        },
      )
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      tooltip: 'Back',
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: query == ""
          ? null
          : apiClient.fetchSuggestions(
              query, Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode),
      builder: (context, snapshot) => query == ''
          ? Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Text('Enter address'),
            )
          : snapshot.hasData
              ? ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
            ListTile(
              title:
              Text((snapshot.data[index] as Suggestion).description!),
              onTap: () {
                close(context, snapshot.data[index] as Suggestion?);
              },
            ),
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
      )
              : Container(child: Text('Loading...')),
    );
  }
}
```

`place_service.dart`

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/http.dart';

class Place {
  String? streetNumber;
  String? street;
  String? city;
  String? zipCode;

  Place({
    this.streetNumber,
    this.street,
    this.city,
    this.zipCode,
  });

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Place(streetNumber: $streetNumber, street: $street, city: $city, zipCode: $zipCode)';
  }
}

class Suggestion {
  final String? placeId;
  final String? description;

  Suggestion(this.placeId, this.description);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Suggestion(description: $description, placeId: $placeId)';
  }
}

class PlaceApiProvider {
  final client = Client();

  PlaceApiProvider(this.sessionToken);

  final sessionToken;

  static final String androidKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE';
  static final String iosKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE';
  final apiKey = Platform.isAndroid ? androidKey : iosKey;

  Future<List<Suggestion>?> fetchSuggestions(String input, String lang) async {
    final request =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$input&key=$apiKey&sessiontoken=$sessionToken';
    final response = await client.get(Uri.parse(request));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final result = json.decode(response.body);
      if (result['status'] == 'OK') {
        // compose suggestions in a list
        return result['predictions']
            .map<Suggestion>((p) => Suggestion(p['place_id'], p['description']))
            .toList();
      }
      if (result['status'] == 'ZERO_RESULTS') {
        return [];
      }
      throw Exception(result['error_message']);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to fetch suggestion');
    }
  }

  Future<Place> getPlaceDetailFromId(String? placeId) async {
    final request =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=$placeId&fields=address_component&key=$apiKey&sessiontoken=$sessionToken';
    final response = await client.get(Uri.parse(request));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final result = json.decode(response.body);
      if (result['status'] == 'OK') {
        final components =
            result['result']['address_components'] as List<dynamic>;
        // build result
        final place = Place();
        components.forEach((c) {
          final List type = c['types'];
          if (type.contains('street_number')) {
            place.streetNumber = c['long_name'];
          }
          if (type.contains('route')) {
            place.street = c['long_name'];
          }
          if (type.contains('locality')) {
            place.city = c['long_name'];
          }
          if (type.contains('postal_code')) {
            place.zipCode = c['long_name'];
          }
        });
        return place;
      }
      throw Exception(result['error_message']);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to fetch suggestion');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try adding bang(`!`) operator like `snapshot.data!....`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I tried using bang(!) operator but got another errors
1)The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object' : 58
2)The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object' :60
3)The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Object' :63

Answer (score 1):

The solution is probably this:

`builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Suggestion>> snapshot)`

instead of this:

`builder: (context,  snapshot)`

then you can do something like:

```
List<Suggestion>? suggestions = snapshot.data;

if ( suggestions != null && suggestions.length > 0) {
```